# Why Are Some Sets Not Measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to understand why you can't evaluate a measure on generic sets (the ones in Banach-Tarski construction). That is, I want to know why when considering $m(X)$, we have to restrict our attention to $X\in\sigma$-algebras instead of letting any generic set $X$ be called measurable. Let $B=S^2\setminus (0,0,0)$. $B$ can be split into four disjoint sets $A_i$ where their union is two copies of $B$. If we suppose we can define $m(A_i)$ for each $A_i$, we want to derive a contradiction using the properties of measures. So we have $m(B)=m(\cup_{i=1}^4A_i)=\sum_{i=1}^4m(A_i)=2m(B)\implies m(B)=0\implies m(A_i)=0$ for each $A_i$. I don't see what the contradiction is though. Obviously this doesn't capture the essence of what we want to mean by "volume", but why can't we just say $m(A_i)=0$?

Comment: $m(B)$ is decidedly not supposed to be zero. A ball of positive radius has positive volume.

Comment: The way I read it in my textbook, the wording seemed to suggest it's impossible to assign a value $m(A_i)$ for any measure, not just a particular one. So the problem is that we're implicitly using the Lebesgue measure? If we used a measure $m(X)=0$ for every $X$ there's no problem, right?

Comment: Yes, they're implicitly talking about the Lebesgue measure: assuming the axiom of choice, not every set can be Lebesgue measurable. Some less useful measures can be defined on the $\sigma$-algebra of all sets, like the  one that's $0$ for every set, or the one that's $\infty$ for every nonempty set, or the "counting measure" that gives the size of finite sets and $\infty$ otherwise.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much

Comment: It's not possible to extend Lebesgue measure on $R^3$ to every subset of $R^3$ and still have a finitely additive measure. Without finite additivity there's not much use in assigning values of the measure to all of the subsets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why this is a contradiction is because this argument can be applied to **any** starting set. Therefore we wind up concluding that every set has measure zero, which is boring. Properly stated, the theorem says that any translation and rotation invarient finitely additive **nontrivial** measure on $\mathbb{R}^3$ has non-measurable sets.

Comment: As I mentioned, there *are* translation-invariant measures other than the zero measure that cause no problem here: for example, the counting measure. If by non-trivial you mean something equivalent to "assigns a finite positive measure to the unit cube", then if your $\sigma$-algebra contains all the Borel sets then a translation-invariant measure is forced to be a multiple of the Lebesgue measure. Thus, I would say that this really is about the Lebesgue measure, both because that's the most likely context in the textbook, and because the Lebesgue measure is the only interesting case.